# How to Solve Getting Different Result of Query in MAMP MySQL Server and TablePlus MySQL Server?

Tags: mysql, mamp, table-plus

I have a table and I want to run a query, first I've tried the MySQL server on MAMP and I've got this result:
[image]

After that, I imported my table into the TablePlus MySQL server, and this time I'm getting a different result.
[image]

Why the result of this query is different from the MAMP's result?
How can I solve this inequality?

Comment: first check whether the total no of rows without the WHERE conditions show up as the same on both or not. Then run the same query in CLI and see what you get from that

Comment: @RavishaHesh When I delete the WHERE condition the results are the same.

Comment: try `...WHERE date(created_at) BETWEEN date('2021-10-19 00:00:00') AND date('2021-10-23 23:59:59')`

Comment: @RavishaHesh It doesn't make difference. I think it's related to the created_at and timestamp format because my 17258 row has a different created_at value with the 17258th row in tablePlus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the timezone in tablePlus and with changing the timezone configuration I'm getting the same result:
[image]